# Convert from C# to VB error

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates

I have converted a working C# class that embeds xls files to windows forms application to vb.

I am getting the error:

> "Overload resolution Failed because no accessible'Navigate' accepts this number of arguments"

at the following line:

from:

`this.WebBrowserExcel.Navigated+=new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(this.OnWebBrowserExcelNavigated);`

to:

`Me.WebBrowserExcel.Navigate += New System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnWebBrowserExcelNavigated)`

i have also tried:

`Me.WebBrowserExcel.Navigate += New System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(Me.OnWebBrowserExcelNavigated)`

but i get error:

> Error 13 Delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The direct translation of C#'s `delegate +=` is `AddHandler` in VB:

```
AddHandler Me.WebBrowserExcel.Navigated, AddressOf Me.OnWebBrowserExcelNavigated
```

Alternatively, you could *do it the VB.NET way* and use [WithEvents and the Handles Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz.aspx):

```
Function OnWebBrowserExcelNavigated(...) Handles WebBrowserExcel.Navigate
    ...
End Function
```

Comment: Me.WebBrowserExcel.Navigate is not a handler thus i can not put an addhandler. Me.WebBrowserExcel.Navigated is the handler. The class was using the navigate and not the navigated.

Comment: ok i have used WebBrowserExcel.Navigated with an addhandler and worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for fixing the typo!

Answer (score 2):

When you handle event in vbnet, you should use `AddHandler`.

Try this:

```
AddHandler Me.WebBrowserExcel.Navigate, AddressOf Me.OnWebBrowserExcelNavigated
```

or take a look at this example:

```
Public Class RoutedEventAddRemoveHandler

    Private Sub MakeButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim b2 As Button = New Button()
        b2.Content = "New Button"
        AddHandler b2.Click, AddressOf Onb2Click
        root.Children.Insert(root.Children.Count, b2)
        DockPanel.SetDock(b2, Dock.Top)
        text1.Text = "Now click the second button..."
        b1.IsEnabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Onb2Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
        text1.Text = "New Button (b2) Was Clicked!!"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ok i have used WebBrowserExcel.Navigated with an addhandler and worked. Thanks!!!